# bootstrap gradient less file compile error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, less, gradient

I created a gradient.less file within bootstrap less folder.

In the gradient.less file I have a class named  .linear-gradient. 
I imported and placed the gradient.less file at the top of the bootstrap.less file
I created a variable named @jumbo-gradient in the file named variable.less.

now it's not working and showing a message @jumbo-gradient is undefined.

How do I add or import linear-gradient class from gradient.less file as a value for the variable @jumbo-gradient in the variable.less file?

Is it possible?

Here is my gradient class:

```
.linear-gradient( @dir: top, @start-color: #eee, @end-color: #aaa ) {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(@dir, @start-color 0%, @end-color 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(@dir, @start-color 0%, @end-color 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(@dir, @start-color 0%, @end-color 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(@dir, @start-color 0%, @end-color 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(@dir, @start-color 0%, @end-color 100%);
    .linear-gradient-ie( @dir, @start-color, @end-color);
}
```

Comment: Did you import the `gradient.less` file after `variables.less` ?

Comment: no. before variable.less file. 

like this : 

// Core variables and mixins
import "gradient.less";
import "variables.less";
import "mixins.less";

Comment: Not sure, but shouldn't it go after `variables.less` ?

Comment: Mmm, and how the code in your question is related to `@jumbo-gradient` variable? Show the code where it's defined and used (i.e. the code you get the error with).